# While updating data for one field shows undefined for other in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

In a Grid, certain records are populated, which also includes two input fields one for date and other for text. When changed data for date, text data gets undefined and when text is changed date is undefined which can be observed in console. After changing data I need to save it in the function. Please refer to the code below:

Following is the updateGrid function which I'm getting from Grid

```
<Grid
        OnTextCallback={updateGrid}
        DateCallBack={updateGrid}
      />
```

```
const updateGrid = (data) => {
    if (Array.isArray(newDataHere) && newDataHere?.length > 0) {
      
      // newDataHere is an array of data
      const tempData = newDataHere;
      tempData.map((x) => {
        if (data.id === x.id) {
          x.name = data.textVal;
        }
        if (data.id === x.id) {
          x.Establish = data.dateVal;
        }
      });
      setDataAll(tempData);
    }
    console.log("tempdataNew", dataAll);
  };
```

As seen from above code, both text and date has similar id which is received from Grid, but, when changed one field shows undefined for another field. How can this be tackled?

Please refer to codesandbox --> https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-aryabhata-95o2sy?file=/src/Table.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Grid` component only returns `dateVal` or `textVal` with each kind of value change, so you cannot change them both together.

For the fix, you can add a condition to check your value availabilities from each value change

```
  const updateGrid = (data) => {
    if (Array.isArray(newDataHere) && newDataHere?.length > 0) {
      const tempData = newDataHere;
      tempData.forEach((x) => {
        if (data.id === x.id) {
          //if textVal is available, we will update
          if (data.textVal) {
            x.name = data.textVal;
          }
          //if dateVal is available, we will update
          if (data.dateVal) {
            x.Establish = data.dateVal;
          }
        }
      });
      setDataAll(tempData);
    }
    console.log("tempdataNew", dataAll);
  };
```

[The sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-panka-khqr7v?file=/src/Table.js:1433-1889)

Comment: Perfect solution.... only one last thing... I'm unable to get data on first instance but, when second time clicked on date or text, displays data in console. If possible can you please help in that

Comment: For the first rendering, you assigned `[]` to `dataAll` state (`const [dataAll, setDataAll] = useState([]);`), so that's why it's empty initially. For the fix, you should modify it to `const [dataAll, setDataAll] = useState(newData);`. By the way, if you think my solution is good, please help me to mark it as the question's solution. That will give a little support to me as well as our community. Thank you!~ :D @PrakashPatil

Comment: Yes... I did it but, its not working

Comment: I just modified the sandbox with `useEffect` change https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-panka-khqr7v?file=/src/Table.js:204-385. I think you also need to update `dataAll` whenever you get `newData` @PrakashPatil

Comment: Thanks for quick response.... but still not working as expected

Comment: That's weird though... I verified it just now https://ibb.co/qW6vY0y. Did you modify anything in `useEffect`? @PrakashPatil

Comment: Ok fine.... but in the starting on changing date data, we are getting it in 'Array' right... how can we get into in array of object only? The one which we see on second time

Comment: You can move it to `useEffect(() => { if(allData) { setDataAll(newArrayOfObj); } },[allData])` instead. You can check it out here again https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-panka-khqr7v?file=/src/Table.js:419-670 @PrakashPatil

Comment: Thanks bro... you're awesome... really thanks again for you quick response